# Error loading Project cannot load modules in PhpStorm

Tags: macos, ide, phpstorm, osx-elcapitan

I have a problem with my PhpStorm IDE. I deleted the `.idea` folder to some project that I wouldn't in the project list. But now, when I open the IDE with my default project, I have the error in title:

> Error loading Project: cannot load 3 modules.

In this window I can "Remove Selected" but nothing happens.
I tried to close project from File menu and add new project from existing folder but nothing happens.

I'm using PhpStorm on a Mac. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there were some manipulations with Sources in this default project where you receive that error.
Close all instances of PhpStorm, remove **.idea/modules.xml** file and see how this will go when you will start the project again.

Comment: .idea/modules.xml is the culprit most the time. Particularly if you mark one of the module paths as Excluded folder. That prevents PHPStorm to load them and it hangs.